# html5 drawing multiple canvas images

Tags: html, image, canvas

i've got a problem with canvas in html. I want to draw multiple canvas images. 
I have created a loop which creates multiple canvas and then i want to draw in each canvas an image.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= playerStuff.MovingCards.length; i++){
    $("#playersField").append("<canvas id='movingCardsField"+i+"' height='"+movingCardSizeY+"'\n\
                             width='"+movingCardSizeX+"'\n\
                             data='"+playerStuff.MovingCards[i-1].movePoints+"'></canvas>");
    var imgObj = new Image();
    var drawField = document.getElementById('movingCardsField'+i).getContext("2d"); 
    imgObj.onload = function(){
            drawField.drawImage(imgObj, 0,0);
    };
    imgObj.src = "./img/moveCards/"+playerStuff.MovingCards[i-1].name;
}
```

The result is that only the last canvas has a drawn image. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please dont use JQuery for this. In generally i'm not a friend of JQuery but thats my personally opinion,but here you should really dont useit, use the DOM its much more faster.

```
var playersField=document.getElementById("playersField");
var canvasElements=new Array ();
var canvasElement, drawField,imgObj;
var drawFields=new Array ();

for (var i = 0; i <= playerStuff.MovingCards.length; i++)
  {
  canvasElement=document.createElement ("canvas");
  canvasElement.height=movingCardSizeY;
  canvasElement.width=movingCardSizeX;
  canvasElement.data=playerStuff.MovingCards[i-1].movePoints;
  playersField.appendChild(canvasElement);

  drawField=canvasElement.getContext("2d");
  drawFields.push (drawField);
  imgObj = new Image();
  imgObj.src = "./img/moveCards/"+playerStuff.MovingCards[i-1].name;
  imgObj.index=i;

  imgObj.onload = function (){
        drawFields[this.index].drawImage(this, 0,0);
  };
```

Comment: you have to rearrange your Movingcards starting with index 0. why do a lot of people start with index 1 instead of index 0. i#ve seen this a lot times. for what is that good, leaving the first array field empty?

Comment: This worked. Thank you. But ive got a strange problem now. I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. But everything is working. Even when i print player.stuff.movingcards[0].name on the console it is working.

Comment: Please show line its throws this error and some context

Comment: after looking through i think the problem is MovingCards [i-1], which i copied from your script. it must be MovingCards[i].. because i goes from 0 to ...  and the first value for i=0 and MovingCards [0-1] =-1 does not exist

Answer (score 0):

that is becouse onload y asinchronous, when al the iterations of the for has ended, the onload is probably that has not been called. then drawField variable is the last element. to solve this in a fast way (but not the cleanest solution)

the scope of a varaible is not as it could be in c++ or other languages.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= playerStuff.MovingCards.length; i++){
    (function(element) {
        $("#playersField").append("<canvas id='movingCardsField"+i+"' height='"+movingCardSizeY+"'\n\
                         width='"+movingCardSizeX+"'\n\
                         data='"+element.movePoints+"'></canvas>");
        var imgObj = new Image();
        var drawField = document.getElementById('movingCardsField'+i).getContext("2d"); 
        imgObj.onload = function(){
            drawField.drawImage(imgObj, 0,0);
        };
      imgObj.src = "./img/moveCards/"+element.name;
})(playerStuff.MovingCards[i - 1]);
```

}

this may do the trick, more or less, I didn't check twice the code

btw is not very efficient also

this should be something better

```
var domElement = $("#playersField");
var canvasStart = "<canvas id='movingCardsField";
var canvasEnd = "' height='"+movingCardSizeY + "'width='" + movingCardSizeX + "' data='" + element.movePoints + "'></canvas>";

function createCanvas(element) {
    var canvas = canvasStart + (i + 1) + canvasEnd;
    domElement.append(canvas);

    var imgObj = new Image();
    var drawField = document.getElementById('movingCardsField' + (i + 1)).getContext("2d"); 
    imgObj.onload = function() {
        drawField.drawImage(imgObj, 0,0);
    };
    imgObj.src = "./img/moveCards/" + element.name;
}

for (var i = 0; i < playerStuff.MovingCards.length; i++) {
    createCanvas(playerStuff.MovingCards[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This also worked. But im not sure if i understood everything. So the problem was, that the onload function wasn't finished when the loop ended? So your solution is, that you call in each loop the function and no variable is overwritten?